# My system powers down when I insert a disk into my drive

Tags: power, optical-drive

I have a problem.

My system is powered off when i insert disk on my drive. Some time it working.

I replaced the drive but same problem.

Will it be a SMBS problem? What i have to check?

**Edited:**

**Turned off** : When disc is inserted system dies (i.e Totally powered off) I cant powered on again. I have to unplug the main cables and i again i have to connect to get restart.

Comment: What sort of power off? Does it just die? Start shutting down normally? Does it restart after?

Comment: If you mean it how you write it then: Turn your system on before inserting a disk.

Comment: I have edited the post please refer.

Comment: Mac or PC? You manage to call it a 'system' all through your question rather than refering to it as a PC or Mac.

Comment: I am refering to PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. Apparently my PSU (power supply unit) was faulty; after replacing it, the problem went away. Try borrowing a PSU from a friend and try it out; it might just help you solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps he can first see if it's just the cable going to the disk drive?

Comment: This does sound like a power issue like the power supply can't handle the energy draw from the disk drive. That being said, the normal power draw of a working floppy drive is next to nothing. There is the possibility that something failed with the drive and is shorting out. That could cause a sudden increase in voltage draw from the disk. How old is the drive and do you have a known good spare you can swap it with? Depending on what you are doing, you might want to grab a USB disk drive so it doesn't have a direct connection to the power supply.

Comment: I thought so and I have bought a new drive and tried But same problem